# Python basemap with scatter plot

Tags: python, scatter-plot, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to plot the location of NYC and Berlin on a basemap with a scatter plot.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

m = Basemap(projection='robin',lon_0=0,resolution='l')

# New York and Berlin
lats = (13.388889,52.516667)
lons = (-74.0059,40.7127)

m.drawcountries(color='#ffffff', linewidth=0.5)
m.fillcontinents(color='#c0c0c0',lake_color='#ffffff')

x, y = m(lons, lats)  # transform coordinates
plt.scatter(x, y, 10, marker='o', color='Red') 

plt.savefig("filename.svg", figsize=(24,12))
plt.show()
```

However, only one of the points shows up on the map at the wrong location.
[image]

Can anyone assisst me and point out why one point shows up at the wrong location and the other dot doe snot show up at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matter is your **coordinate definition**. You are mixing `longitude` and `latitude`. After checking the coordinates of Berlin and New York, it comes the following definition:

```
# Berlin & New York
lats = [52.516667, 40.730610 ]
lons = [13.388889, -73.935242]
```

Here the whole code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

m = Basemap(projection='robin', lon_0=0, resolution='l')

# Berlin & New York
lats = [52.516667, 40.730610 ]
lons = [13.388889, -73.935242]

m.drawcountries(color='#ffffff', linewidth=0.5)
m.fillcontinents(color='#c0c0c0', lake_color='#ffffff')

x, y = m(lons, lats)
plt.plot(x, y, 'bo', color='r', markersize=5)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Silly mistake. Thank you for your support! Much appreciated :) Works perfectly fine!